# How to implement SSL with embedded mongoose

Tags: c, ssl, mongoose-web-server

I try to add SSL to my web server implemented with mongoose, but I don't manage to make it work. I have openssl installed and I try to follow the documentation there https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/docs/SSL.md

I have SSL enable:

```
#define NS_ENABLE_SSL
```

This is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct mg_server *server;
  char port[10] = "8000";
  const char * _port;

  if (argc > 1) {
    strcpy(port, argv[1]);
  }

  // Create and configure the server
  server = mg_create_server(NULL, ev_handler);

  mg_set_option(server, "listening_port", port);
  _port = mg_get_option(server, "listening_port");
  if (strlen(_port)) {
    printf("Starting on port %s\n", _port);
    for (;;) {
      mg_poll_server(server, 1000);
    }
  }
  else {
    printf("Cannot start on port %s\n", port);
  }

  // Cleanup, and free server instance
  mg_destroy_server(&server);

  return 0;
}
```

And I have case *MG_AUTH: return MG_TRUE;* in ev_handler function.

I run my server with:

```
sudo ./hihttpd 80,ssl://443:ssl.pem
```

ssl.pem is in the same folder as hihttpd.

https://127.0.0.1/ return me SSL connection error :-/

You can checkout everything on githut https://github.com/apiel/hihttpd/blob/master/hihttpd.c

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the option to set the certificate path?

```
mg_set_option(server,"ssl_certificate", "../ssl.pem");
```